# Calculate custom score based on function_score with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement custom scoring within an ElasticSearch query.

Before describing the problem, I'll describe my use case.

I have an entity `Item` with several fields:

- `types` (keyword): a list of types
- `themes` (keyword): a list of types
- `location`: the location of the item

My query consists in:

- First targetting a subset of items. Items that have `TYPE1` but don't have `TYPE2` and `TYPE3` for example
- Second defining rules to calculate the score. Items that have `TYPE4` must be boosted by 2. Items that have `THEME1` must be boosted by 3. Items within a provided polygon must be boosted by 4.

Here is the query I tried:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost": 1,
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "types": {
                  "value": "TYPE1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "types": {
                      "value": [
                        "TYPE2",
                        "TYPE3"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "themes": "THEME1"
            }
          },
          "weight": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "types": "TYPE4"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "geo_polygon": {
              "location": {
                "points": [ ... ]
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

On this request, I got this error:

```
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "no [query] registered for [not]",
```

So I think the problem is at the level of the `not` block...

If I remove this block, the request is successful but the scores aren't the expected ones (value `0` for all).

I enabled `explain` mode and I can see this:

```
"_explanation": {
    "value": 0,
    "description": "function score, product of:",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 0,
        "description": "ConstantScore(types:TYPE1)^0.0",
        "details": []
      },
      {
        "value": 1,
        "description": "min of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 1,
            "description": "No function matched",
            "details": []
          },
          {
            "value": 3.4028235e+38,
            "description": "maxBoost",
            "details": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

So my questions are:

- How to use the `not` block for this query?
- How to calculate score based on `function_score`?

Thanks for your help,
Thierry

Comment: try `match` instead of `term`. That should get your filters to match. Guess the way the field is indexed and your search term are not exactly the same.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `not`-Query in ElasticSearch. Remove that block and put the queries on TYPE2 and TYPE3 in a `must_not`-block.